# Swift - JSON anyobject conversion to String failing for tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, neo4j

I'm working with a JSON array of dictionaries:

```
var objects: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>()
```

This is returned from a Theo4j server using Neo (open source swift interface for Neo4j)

I'm struggling to convert the data into a String in order to retrieve the data into a TableView.

Here is an example of returned data from my JSON query:

```
objects = [["id": <null>, "born": 1964, "name": Keanu Reeves], ["id": <null>, "born": 1967, "name": Carrie-Anne Moss], ["id": <null>, "born": 1961, "name": Laurence Fishburne], ["id": <null>, "born": 1960, "name": Hugo Weaving], ["id": <null>, "born": 1967, "name": Andy Wachowski], ["id": <null>, "born": 1965, "name": Lana Wachowski], ["id": <null>, "born": 1952, "name": Joel Silver], ["id": <null>, "born": <null>, "name": Ann], ["id": <null>, "born": <null>, "name": Dan]]
```

I'm trying to pull the name and born data (when exists) into the tableview.  Since the AnyObject field of the dictionary does not have quotation marks, is that causing problems with the conversion?  Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    executeCypherQuery()
    let object = objects[indexPath.row]
    print("Object is: \(objects)")
    print("Hello")
    cell.textLabel!.text = object["name"] as! String
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object["born"] as! String
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

I get an error saying it is unable to convert the data to a String (I also tried converting to NSString).

I tried running some code in a playground and noted that it was confused by the AnyObject data (such as names) being listed as it is shown here.  Since there can be two words of data for a name, it was expecting a "," to separate them but that would not be the correct formatting.

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:  Here is the JSON parsing code from the open source project Theo for Neo4j:

```
    public func executeCypher(query: String, params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?, completionBlock: Client.TheoCypherQueryCompletionBlock?) -> Void {

    // TODO: need to move this over to use transation http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html

    var cypherPayload: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["query" : query]

    if let unwrappedParams: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = params {
        cypherPayload["params"] = unwrappedParams
    }

    let cypherResource: String = self.baseURL + "/db/data/cypher"
    let cypherURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: cypherResource)!
    let cypherRequest: Request = Request(url: cypherURL, credentials: self.credentials)

    cypherRequest.postResource(cypherPayload, forUpdate: false, successBlock: {(data, response) in

        if (completionBlock != nil) {

            if let responseData: NSData = data {

                dispatch_async(self.parsingQueue, {

                    let JSON: AnyObject! = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

                    let jsonAsDictionary: [String:[AnyObject]]! = JSON as! [String:[AnyObject]]
                    let cypher: Cypher = Cypher(metaData: jsonAsDictionary)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        completionBlock!(cypher: cypher, error: nil)
                    })
                })

            } else {
                //TRAVIS EDIT: UNNECESSARY?
                //completionBlock!(cypher: nil, error: self.unknownEmptyResponseBodyError(response))
            }
        }

        }, errorBlock: {(error, response) in

            if (completionBlock != nil) {
                completionBlock!(cypher: nil, error: error)
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: What does the raw JSON look like? What is logged by `print("Object is: \(objects)")`?

Comment: You also might try: `print(object["name"]?.classForCoder)`

Comment: Raw JSON: Object is: [["id": <null>, "born": 1964, "name": Keanu Reeves], ["id": <null>, "born": 1967, "name": Carrie-Anne Moss], ["id": <null>, "born": 1961, "name": Laurence Fishburne], ["id": <null>, "born": 1960, "name": Hugo Weaving], ["id": <null>, "born": 1967, "name": Andy Wachowski], ["id": <null>, "born": 1965, "name": Lana Wachowski], ["id": <null>, "born": 1952, "name": Joel Silver], ["id": <null>, "born": <null>, "name": Ann], ["id": <null>, "born": <null>, "name": Dan]]

Comment: This is what JSON typically looks like: http://www.w3schools.com/json/ What are you showing us is after the JSON has been parsed into an Array.

Comment: object["name"]?.classForCoder gives me a similar error, cannot assign value of type 'AnyClass?' to type 'String?'

Comment: Ok, so if it's already parsed into an array, that still leaves me with the same problem.  How do I get that to show up into my tableview since it won't let me convert it to String?

Comment: Won't calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside cellForRowAtIndexPath cause an infinite loop? At the very least it is bad.

Comment: Anyway, as I suggested you might try to see what type the compiler thinks "name" is by placing `print(object["name"]?.classForCoder)`immediately after `print("Hello")` then checking the console. I wasn't suggesting that adding that line of code would solve your issue. If it is anything other than NSString or Optional(NSString) your JSON has not been parse/formatted correctly. This is the code I have a in a playground https://gist.github.com/bgayman/d1221fe5fbe634d7d5a1 Perhaps you can spot the difference.

Comment: Please post the code where you load the JSON. That is the best place to do the conversion.

Comment: print(object["name"]?.classForCoder)  returned Optional(NSString).  I'll add the JSON code above in just a minute.  It's from an open source Neo4j project called Theo.